# Eclipse / PyDev - Remove path from editor tabs when two files with same name are opened

Tags: eclipse, pydev, eclipse-luna

I'm currently using Elipse Luna, and I'm trying to figure out how to remove the path name from the editor tabs when multiple files with the same name but different directories are opened (see screenshot).

[image]

So, in other words, keep the file name, but remove the path name inside the parentheses.

I've done this in the past with previous versions of Eclipse, but I can't for the life of me remember how I did it. I just find that path names take up a lot of real estate in my editor and it doesn't take long before tabs are hidden away.

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot? If I'm understanding your question correctly, my Eclipse Luna doesn't do that per default.

Comment: Wish I could, but I'm sort of a newbie at StackFlow. I need 4 more rep points before I can post images. The only hint I can provide is that I was able to change a Preference setting in a previous version of Eclipse and it removed the path in the parenthesis. Unfortunately, I can't remember what that setting was or where to find it, or if it even exists anymore in Luna.

Comment: oh yeah, didn't think of that. Can you post it somewhere else, then I could edit it into your question.

Comment: This is the best I can do. http://i.imgur.com/vpC0YQS.png. I should also mention I'm using the PyDev plugin, but I don't know if that matters in this case.

Comment: great! Is this the PHP plugin? Maybe it's a feature of that.

Comment: Should have fully read your previous comment :D Still my theory that it's the plugin responsible.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still getting used to 'Enter=add comment'. I edited my previous answer that I'm using the PyDev plugin. I see nothing in the PyDev settings that would suggest it's a part of that, but I might be overlooking something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct that this is a Pydev setting.

Go to Preferences -> PyDev -> Editor caption/icon
and change Django modules handling: to
"Show as a regular module"